# Start a Project with the help of Kotlin in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

**I am new in Kotlin for android and i have just started to learn.Please let me know how i should have a knowledge about Kotlin for creating  a project in Android with the help of Kotlin.?**

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/hello-world) link to learn basic syntax of Kotlin.

This tutorial is with very good examples and very helpful for beginners.

If you want to learn some android basic with kotlin [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/learn-kotlin-while-developing-an-android-app-introduction-567e21ff9664) link can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no link better than [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html) to learn Kotlin language for development.

You can refer to this link.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search or Youtube search will yield all the info that you want, to help get you started. I have gathered some of them here which I used.

- [Kotlin In One Video](https://youtu.be/H_oGi8uuDpA) by Derek Banas (Youtube)
- [Kotlin Tutorials Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Org0vh-VSgA&list=PLsyeobzWxl7rooJFZhc3qPLwVROovGCfh) by Telusko Learnings (Youtube)
- You can also check out the Kotlin Developer Course on Udemy by Rob Percival and Nick Walter (Paid Course)